# Error with yasa in mne. Error unexpected keyword argument 'vmin'

Tags: python, mne-python

[image: yasa - mne]

```
import yasa
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series([4, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3, 5],
index=['F4', 'F3', 'C4', 'C3', 'P3', 'P4', 'Oz'],
name='Values'
yasa.topoplot(data,title='My first topoplot')
```

#----- output------

```
TypeError: plot_topomap() got an unexpeced keyword argument 'vmin't
```

I change the value vmin and vmax, but it keeps the error